# Get a random element from ArrayList, add to another ArrayList and delete the element from first ArrayList Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, random, arraylist

I would like to know how to delete a randomly selected item from an arraylist and add that selected item to another empty arraylist.

An Additonal (Optional): I would like to also know how to compare elements in an ArrayList with another ArrayList. This one is a pain in my patuski.

Comment: Removed misc commentary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well to move an element from one ArrayList to the other you *can* do something like this:

```
ArrayList< SomeClass > firstList;
ArrayList< SomeClass > secondList;
int randomlySelectedIndex; //initialize this to be random
SomeClass element = firstList.get( randomlySelectedIndex );
firstList.remove( randomlySelectedIndex );
secondList.add( randomlySelectedIndex );
```

As for comparing elements from 2 lists, you could make a compare method like so:

```
int compare( SomeClass first, SomeClass second ) {
    //return 0, 1 or -1 depending on your criteria of how first relates to second
}
```

and then use the compare method when iterating through both lists

```
int result;
for( int x = 0; x < firstList.size(); x++ ) {
    for( int y = 0; y < secondList.size(); y++ ) {
        result = compare( firstList.get( x ), secondList.get( y ) );
        if( result == 0 ) {
            //do stuff
        }
        else if( result < 0 ) {
            //do stuff
        }
        else {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

please note that you should not be adding or removing elements from either of the arraylists from inside the 2 for loops unless you know the consequences of doing so.

Comment: Thanks for this, I can work with this, I was skeptical on using a nested loop, but I guess I won't be able to avoid it

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick

```
List<T> list;
List<T> emptyList;
...
Random rand = new Random();
int randomIndex = rand.getInt() % list.size();
T item = list.remove(randomIndex);
emptyList.add(item);
```

As far a comparing two lists, you should clarify what exactly you want to compare.  Also, since the two questions are fairly different, you may want to ask it in a separate post.

Comment: Thanks for this, this makes sense, I will be able to incorporate this to Jack's Answer

Answer (score 1):

You can remove object from the `ArrayList` by calling `remove(int index)` which returns the object that was removed. Then you add that object to the other `ArrayList` with `add()`:

```
SomeObject removedObject = firstList.remove(randomNum);
secondList.add(removedObject);
```

Note: make sure that random number is from 0 to the size of your `ArrayList`.

---

You can compare objects of the same class by implementing `Comparable` interface in that class. See more: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: Thanks for this, I would try to avoid the Comparable Interface, but thanks